# How to insert key/value pair where the key is the value of another pair? Array of hashes Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

Here the array of hashes:

```rb
array = [
{:ID => "aaa", :phase => "alpha", :quantity => 80},
{:ID => "aaa", :phase => "beta", :quantity => 160}
]
```

I'm trying to transform the value of `:phase` into a key and to assign its value taking the value of `:quantity`, as follow:

```rb
array = [
{:ID => "aaa", :"alpha" => 80},
{:ID => "aaa", :"beta" => 160}
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
array = [
  {:ID => "aaa", :phase => "alpha", :quantity => 80},
  {:ID => "aaa", :phase => "beta", :quantity => 160}
]

array.map { |hash| { :ID => hash[:ID], hash[:phase].to_sym => hash[:quantity] } }
#=> [{:ID=>"aaa", :alpha=>80}, {:ID=>"aaa", :beta=>160}]
```

Comment: `map!` for in place...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
array.map do |hash|
  new_key = hash.delete(:phase)
  quantity = hash.delete(:quantity)
  hash[new_key] = quantity
  hash
end
```